# How to delete azure artifact symbol packages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, debug-symbols

I have created a local feed for NuGet packages on our Azure DevOps Service (not Server!).

I use a Pipeline to generate automatically the NuGet packages and use a "Index sources and publish symbols"-Task to publish the Symbols to "Symbol Server in this organization/collection (require azure artifacts)".

I know how to delete old NuGet packages from artifacts (space requirement 0,22 GB), but obviously the symbol packages are not deleted with them (space requiremend 2,49 GB) (local created on my PC both need around 220 MB / 250 MB).

My Question is, is there any way to delete published NuGet Symbol Packages from Azure Artifacts by hand?

Kind regards

Mirko

edit: deleted old published packages from azure artifacts feed, reduces space consumption of the packages itself, but not of the symbols.

Solution: Deleting old Runs of the Pipeline frees the Space within the next 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/symbols?view=azure-devops#qa):

> Q: What's the retention policy for the symbols stored in the Azure
> Pipelines symbol server?
>
> A: Symbols have the same retention as the
> build. When you delete a build, you also delete the symbols that the
> build produced.

Maybe it is worth to check.

Comment: Thanks i will have a look for this =)

Comment: Ok i deleted the NuPkg, but the Symbol Space is still filled with 2.49 GB (Package Space decreased to 0.08 GB).

Comment: If you share the way how you published this I will try to reproduce it and remove it. But please edit your question and provide repro steps.

Comment: 1. i tried it nuget pack -Symbol and nuget push
2. publishing with a "Index Sources & Publish Symbols task"

Comment: thanks, I didn't associate the build with it, so I read it out.

Answer (score 1):

The document mentioned by Krzysztof Madej says `When you delete a build, you also delete the symbols that the build produced`. So you can have a try deleting the build to see if the symbols is deleted with the buid.

Pipelines-->Select the pipeline

[image]

Runs-->Click More-->Delete

[image]

Comment: thank you, i've delete every build on the server, except the last three. As i remember correctly, the deletion takes up to 24h (like in case of the nupkgs, i have deleted on thursday in the late afternoon - friday full space allocation, on monday space was given free).

so hopefully, tomorrow at around 13:30 everything is cleared. :)

Comment: ok that worked, thanks a lot, now space is cleared from the old stuff, but it took nearly 23 hours...

Comment: ok, space is cleared, but the error stays:
59146ms
Response status code does not indicate success: 402 (Payment Required - Artifact cannot be uploaded because max quantity has been exceeded or the payment instrument is invalid. https://aka.ms/artbilling for details.

But i am now below the free 2 GB. *argh*

Comment: In Addition Billing and used space are separately cleared... 
Deleting from space takes around 24h.
Correct Billing takes several days.